# iOS Subview button causing application to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, subview

I added a subview to my main view, the subview has a button on it, but when I select the button on the subview, the application crashes with the following highlited in green:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1), address=0xf0000008
```

The subview has its own *viewcontroller* and *xib* file.

heres some of the code I used:

Subview.h

```
- (IBAction)setDummyTime:(id)sender;
```

Main view.m

```
PickupTimeViewController *pickupTimeView = [[PickupTimeViewController alloc]init];
[selectedView addSubview:pickupTimeView.view];
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't retain it in a `property` this will happen.

Comment: Can you post some code for adding button and subview?

Comment: Sounds like its been dealloc'ed on you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like its been dealloc'ed on you.

Try turning on Zombie mode, crash the app again and see if it points you to whats going on, it will tell which object is trying to do something after being released.

Xcode -> Click your scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics -> Tick Enable Zombie Objects

Another thing to try is to watch your subView in the debug area, this will tell you when your subView is released.

[Example of setting watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BumgQ.png)

Also if you have not already tried it, try keep a strong/retain reference to your subview.

If you can't get it working post the code you create the view with.

EDIT:
in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PickupTimeViewController *pickupTimeView;
```

in .m

```
self.pickupTimeView = [[PickupTimeViewController alloc]init]; 
[selectedView addChildViewController:self.pickupTimeView]; // (i0S5+ only) if the view you add to is a view controller if not use self otherwise.
[selectedView addSubview:pickupTimeView.view];
```

Good luck,
BooRanger

Comment: I enabled Zombie Objects and the log said: "message sent to dealocated instance 0x580..."

Heres some of the code I used

Subview.h
- (IBAction)setDummyTime:(id)sender;

Main view.m
    PickupTimeViewController *pickupTimeView = [[PickupTimeViewController alloc]init];
    [selectedView addSubview:pickupTimeView.view];

Comment: Basically somewhere your not keeping on to the object, try po the memory address and see what it is. The pickupTimeViewController should be added as a child [self addChildViewController:] but i don't reckon thats it and only ios5 up. Also worth setting up a property and trying self.pickupTimeController = ...

Comment: Thanks, the [self addChildViewController:...] did the job, just added that line before I added the subview and it did the job...The subview got added but its controller got dealocated and that was my problem.